# pytesseract not working on digits image

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I would like to use pytesseract to classify the following image:

[image: image of number 5]

but it classifies it as "T".

here's the code:

`txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='-psm 10')`

Answer (score 1):

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
image = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng',config='--tessdata-dir "/tessdata/data/" --oem 2 --psm 6')
print(text)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Narendra Jadhav The explanation is that the image have to be black text on white background.

Comment: The code does not work on mac. Shows tessdata error.